# calculate aggregation and percentage simultaneous after groupBy in scala/Spark Dataset/Dataframe

Tags: scala, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I am learning to work with Scala and spark. It's my first incidents using them. I have some structured Scala DataSet(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) like following format.

```
Region | Id | RecId | Widget | Views | Clicks |  CTR
1      | 1  | 101   |   A    |  5    |    1   |  0.2
1      | 1  | 101   |   B    | 10    |    4   |  0.4
1      | 1  | 101   |   C    |  5    |    1   |  0.2
1      | 2  | 401   |   A    |  5    |    1   |  0.2
1      | 2  | 401   |   D    | 10    |    2   |  0.1
```

`NOTE: CTR = Clicks/Views`

I want to merge the mapping regardless of Widget (i.e using Region, Id, RecID).

The **Expected Output** I want is like following:

```
Region | Id | RecId | Views | Clicks |  CTR
1      | 1  | 101   | 20    |    6   |  0.3
1      | 1  | 101   | 15    |    3   |  0.2
```

What **I am getting** is like below:

```
>>> ds.groupBy("Region","Id","RecId").sum().show()
Region | Id | RecId | sum(Views) | sum(Clicks) |  sum(CTR)
1      | 1  | 101   | 20         |    6        |  0.8
1      | 1  | 101   | 15         |    3        |  0.3
```

I understand that it is summing up all the CTR from original but I want to groupBy as explained but still want to get the expected CTR value. I also don't want to change column names as it is changing in my approach.

Is there any possible way of calculating in such manner. I also have `#Purchases` and `CoversionRate` (#Purchases/Views) and I want to do the same thing with that field also. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Your essential problem is you are mixing data and analytics together. Your last column is actually not data, but is a calculated field. It should be separate to your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the ctr after the aggregation. Try the below code.

`ds.groupBy("Region","Id","RecId")
.agg(sum(col("Views")).as("Views"), sum(col("Clicks")).as("Clicks"))
.withColumn("CTR" , col("Views") / col("Clicks"))
.show()`